# Always exist non-negative/non-positive column in orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

For an orthogonal matrix $Q$, does it always have a non-negative/non-positive column? In other words, is there always a column $j$ such that $Q_{ij}\ge 0$ or $Q_{ij}\le 0$ for all $i$?

Intuitively, consider the 2-D case, if $Q$ is orthogonal, then its columns can represent two perpendicular vectors in the 2-D plain. One of them should point to the first/third orthant and thus has non-negative/non-positive entries. Can we formally prove this in high dimensional space?

Answer (score 1):

No. The matrix
$$
\pmatrix{ -1 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & -1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & -1}
$$
has orthogonal columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your conjecture is false. Here is a counterexample in 3-space.

Consider the matrix that rotates by an angle of $\pi / 6$ about the vector $[1, 1, 1]^T$. Expanding it out, it's
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{3} & \frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{3} & \frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{3} \\
\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Every row and column has one negative element and two positive elements. The matrix is orthogonal.